# How to select a single graph from multiple plot output

Tags: r, plot, glmnet

I'm attemtping to select a single grpah from multiple plot output with "glmnet" function (especially elastic net) in R.

I'm currently dealing with multinomial case; the response variable has 3 or more categories. So I fit the model with explanatory variable X and the response variable y with 3 types of categories. Assume that we already have alpha and lambda values from cross validation using cv.glmnet. I didn't use the argument `type.multinomial = "grouped"`.

```
fit <- glmnet(X, y, alpha = alpha, lambda = lambda, standardize = TRUE, family = "multinomial")
plot(fit, xvar = "lambda")
```

`fit` is then the elastic net model. I know that `plot(fit, xvar = "lambda")` shows the coefficients path something like this:

[image: Elastic net coefficients]

However, when it is multinomial case, R generates multiple coefficient plots at the same time: for example when y has three categories, then R shows 3 coefficient plots. But I need to select only one graph out of them. I tried to find a way in google, but failed. Is there any way that I can try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could modify the `glmnet:::plot.multnet` method for this and add a `which=` option similar to that in `stats:::plot.lm`.

```
plot.multnet <- function(x, xvar=c("norm", "lambda", "dev"), label=FALSE, 
          type.coef=c("coef", "2norm"), which=x$classnames, ...) {
  xvar <- match.arg(xvar)
  type.coef <- match.arg(type.coef)
  if (!all(which %in% x$classnames)) {
    warning(sprintf('`which="%s"` not in classnames, defaulting to all', which))
    which <- x$classnames
  }
  beta <- x$beta
  if (xvar == "norm") {
    cnorm1 <- function(beta) {
      whichnz <- nonzeroCoef(beta)
      beta <- as.matrix(beta[whichnz, ])
      apply(abs(beta), 2, sum)
    }
    norm <- apply(sapply(x$beta, cnorm1), 1, sum)
  } else {
    norm <- NULL
  }
  dfmat <- x$dfmat
  if (type.coef == "coef") {
    ncl <- nrow(dfmat)
    clnames <- rownames(dfmat)
    lapply(which, function(z) glmnet:::plotCoef(beta[[z]], norm, x$lambda, dfmat[z, ], x$dev.ratio, 
                                label=label, xvar=xvar, ylab=paste("Coefficients: Response", 
                                                                   grep(z, clnames, value=TRUE))))
  } else {
    dfseq <- round(apply(dfmat, 2, mean), 1)
    glmnet:::plotCoef(coefnorm(beta, 2), norm, x$lambda, dfseq, x$dev.ratio, 
             label=label, xvar=xvar, ylab="Coefficient 2Norms", 
             ...)
  }
}
```

### Usage

```
fit1 <- glmnet::glmnet(x, y, family="multinomial")

plot(fit1, xvar='lambda', which='c')
```

[image]

I implemented a warning if a certain layer is not present, then by default all layers are plotted as before.

```
plot(fit1, xvar='lambda', which='foo')
# Warning message:
# In plot.multnet(fit1, xvar = "lambda", which = 1) :
#   `which="foo"` not in classnames, defaulting to all
```

---

*Data:*

```
set.seed(42)
x <- matrix(rnorm(100 * 20), 100, 20)
y <- sample(letters[1:3], 100, replace=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way, hacking the code of `plot.multnet`, like in [jay.sf's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74847631/8245406). The hacking is different, though. It doesn't throw a warning when asked to plot all levels. See the code comments on what is done.

The data set and  fit example is taken from the documentation of `plot.multnet`, see, for instance, [here](https://glmnet.stanford.edu/reference/plot.glmnet.html).

```r
library(glmnet)
#> Loading required package: Matrix
#> Loaded glmnet 4.1-4

plot.multnet <- 
  function (x, xvar = c("norm", "lambda", "dev"), label = FALSE, 
            type.coef = c("coef", "2norm"), which = NULL, ...) 
  {
    xvar = match.arg(xvar)
    type.coef = match.arg(type.coef)
    beta = x$beta
    if (xvar == "norm") {
      cnorm1 = function(beta) {
        which = glmnet:::nonzeroCoef(beta)
        beta = as.matrix(beta[which, ])
        apply(abs(beta), 2, sum)
      }
      norm = apply(sapply(x$beta, cnorm1), 1, sum)
    }
    else norm = NULL
    dfmat = x$dfmat
    if (type.coef == "coef") {
      ncl = nrow(dfmat)
      clnames = rownames(dfmat)
      #
      if(is.null(which)) {    # if all response values are to be plotted
        seq_ncl <- seq(ncl)   # use the package's loop control variable
      } else {
        seq_ncl <- which      # if not, only the wanted values
      }
      #
      for (i in seq_ncl) {
        glmnet:::plotCoef(beta[[i]], norm, x$lambda, dfmat[i, ], x$dev.ratio, 
                          label = label, xvar = xvar, ylab = paste("Coefficients: Response", 
                                                                   clnames[i]), ...)
      }
    }
    else {
      dfseq = round(apply(dfmat, 2, mean), 1)
      glmnet:::plotCoef(coefnorm(beta, 2), norm, x$lambda, dfseq, x$dev.ratio, 
                        label = label, xvar = xvar, ylab = "Coefficient 2Norms", 
                        ...)
    }
  }


set.seed(2022)
x <- matrix(rnorm(100*20), 100, 20)
g4 <- sample(4, 100, replace = TRUE)
fit3 <- glmnet(x, g4, family = "multinomial")

op <- par(mfrow = c(2, 2))
plot(fit3)
```

[image]

```r
par(op)

plot(fit3, which = 2)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-12-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: You probably missed that I implemented the warning about misspecification on purpose.

Comment: @jay.sf You're right, I had missed that point.